# CMD Replace a string with lines from a txt file

Tags: windows, string, text, cmd, find

im wondering if it is possible to do this:

```
CMD> FIND /I data.txt "use line 1-end of text file as string" >>result.txt
```

Im Norwegian som i dont know how to best describe this.

I need a way to automaticly run every line in a text file as a FIND string.

Answer (score 0):

This steps through `searchterm_textfile.txt` line by line and uses each line to  search in data.txt

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' type "searchterm_textfile.txt" ') do (
find /i "%%a" <data.txt >>result.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `findstr` instead of `find`. See `findstr /?`, especially the option `/g`, which will use all lines in a file as searchstrings.